# document.getElementById('box').style.width="10px"; Doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, css

I cannot seem to get this script to work. Can anyone please help? The DIV's width is not defined. It just stretches across the whole page.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#box{
    height:100px;
    border:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000;
}
</style>
<script>
document.getElementById('box').style.width="10px";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The element does not exist on the page yet. JavaScript can not access/manipulate an element until it has been loaded in the DOM. You can overcome this by moving you `<script>` block to above the closing `</body>`. Or use an window.load event.

An example of the former using your code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/ycWxH/

Answer (score 15):

Your script is running before the `<div>` is rendered on the page. Try it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#box{
    height:100px;
    border:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('box').style.width="10px";
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And don't forget to close your `<body>` and `<html>` tags.

To prove that it is, look at this example. I moved the script back to the `<head>` section and changed the width setting to run when the window is finished loading.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#box{
    height:100px;
    border:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('test');

    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('box').style.width="10px";
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll see the 'test' alert message before the box is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

if you will use jquery it is more easy to do that.
that is if you will only use jquery framework
here is the code

```
$('#box').height(10);
```

Comment: thank you. im still learning jquery. this is very helpful. thank you very much/

Answer (score 0):

just a reminder, `window.onload` is fired when page fully loaded.
refer to http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml

```
<script>
function doMyStuff() = {};


if ( document.addEventListener ) {
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", doMyStuff, false );
} else if ( document ) {
document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {doMyStuff();}
});}
</script>
```